# View two text files at the same time side by side

Tags: editor

I have two text files. Each line represents a line in one language. I need to check if the alignment always fits. Therefore I need a program that displays both text files at the same time with line numbers.

I tried diffuse, but that tries to align the files - if by accident two lines are equal, the whole line-wise visual comparison does not work.

Answer (score 31):

Use Vim, with [`scrollbind`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scrollbind%27) set. For example:

```
vim -O +'windo set scrollbind' /etc/profile /etc/profile.pacnew
```

[image]

With `scrollbind`, if you scroll in one window, the other bound windows also scroll at the same time. To have line numbers, a `~/.vimrc` containing a minimum of the following two lines is enough:

```
set nocompatible
set number
```

Not that you *need* a `vimrc` for this - it can be done entirely from the commandline:

```
vim -NO +'set nu' +'windo set scrollbind' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need `scrollbind`, so it was just `-O` I was missing. I normally use `gt` and `gT` with the `-p` switch for multiple tabs. Alas those shortcuts don't work in this context; it seem `CTRL-W w` does the job (https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39124).

Answer (score 13):

How about a command from early days of Unix?

```
pr -m file1 file2
```

For example:

```
pr  -m English Spanish

2016-01-18 00:34                                                  Page 1

this is something                esto es algo
hello, there                     Hola
```

**Update:** You can fit the output to the size of your terminal by using `less`

```
pr -m file1 file2 | less
```

Comment: If I may suggest so, pipe the output to `less -N` to show the line numbers together.  `pr -m file1 file2 | less -N` .

Answer (score 11):

From the GUI you could try `meld`:

[image: screenshot]

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it should be as much as useful for your purpose.

Additional sections of text will be highlighted in green, different sections of text will be highlighted in blue (and likewise in different sections of text additional characters will be highlighted in a darker blue).

Works also for more than two files at the time.

Comment: I do like & use meld, kdiff3, even sdiff; but if I just want to view two files side by side that are (supposed to be) different (eg, i18n translation resource bundles -- the property matches, value does not; looking for missing properties), then the attempts to line up matching lines & mark lines that are different  is actually a negative.

Comment: @michael_n I'm at a loss to understand why that would be a negative. Maybe I'm missing the point, but if you use `meld` you should have noticed that in cases like the case you're describing lines are highlighted in a lighter blue and the specific additional characters in a darker blue, making the exact difference coming out instantly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and I should have clarified; the problem is that these tools don't have a config option to *expect* and allow that certain differences *should* be there (afaik). In some cases, they consider the whole file too different to even bother to line up. Eg, a useful option (with my example: msg.text="Hello" vs msg.text="Bonjour") would be to ignore part of the two files by either "first N chars", or regexp: "^.*="

Comment: Actually, I think sdiff does have an option to ignore by regexp (but I'm not positive). Still, if it's just free-form text from French & English, there's no need to highlight anything, and any attempt to match up lines -- as I mentioned -- would be a negative. Sometimes, we just wants see files side by side (and that's the essence of the original question, as I understood it).

Comment: @michael_n Actually I just noticed the language comparison thing, for some reason initially I thought they needed a more general purpose text comparison tool. Probably you're right, I should delete this, though I'm also considering that questions titled as generically as this one usually attract lots of visits from search engines (e.g. if I Google "file side by side Ubuntu" this is currently the third result). So maybe it's better if it stays in this case. After all it shouldn't hurt. The exact answer(s) make the top of the stack already.

Comment: @kos Thanks for leaving this answer intact. It's a great side by side editor and I found it very useful comparing a working grub.cfg with a broken one.

Answer (score 5):

On the command line you can use

```
 paste file1 file2 | less -N
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at translations you might find [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) useful. It can display the two texts side by side for you and is made for working with translations.

Comment: instead of just pasting links to solution, you should explain it 'how' too

Comment: This one seems to be limited to working with gettext.